# MySQL - 'Drop User' vs 'delete from user'

Tags: mysql

I need to delete database access from some hosts. There are two options:

This option appears to be the best as I don't need to delete individual users

```
use mysql;
delete from user where host='myhost';
```

In second option below, I need to delete individual users.

```
drop user 'user1'@'myhost';
drop user 'user2'@'myhost';
drop user 'user3'@'myhost';
```

Any idea what is the difference between these options? Any pro and cons?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you use  `DROP USER` Statement it removed one/more accounts + their accounts privileges.

When you use `DELETE User` it's just an SQL command which effects for table(s).

> `DROP` is always more powerful than `delete`

---

Or You can use [`REVOKE`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-delete-remove-user-account-in-mysql-mariadb/) to remove all permeation granted

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'user'@'myhost';
```

**Privileges  are**

1. ALL PRIVILEGES – grants all privileges to the MySQL user
2. CREATE – allows the user to create databases and tables
3. DROP - allows the user to drop databases and tables
4. DELETE - allows the user to delete rows from specific MySQL table
5. INSERT - allows the user to insert rows into specific MySQL table
6. SELECT – allows the user to read the database
7. UPDATE - allows the user to update table rows

---

Read More about [DROP USER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-user.html)

Comment: @Rahul also read that note about *"DROP USER does not automatically close any open user sessions"* ... When you need to be sure there gone gone, use `SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST` and possibly `KILL` sleeping connection(s) from that user aswell.to `"kick"` (close) those connection(s) from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the database tables requires a `flush privileges` call to refresh the cached data. Also, you have to make sure that you manually delete all user AND privileges (e.g., for tables, columns) manually.

Grant/drop user work immediately.

Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privilege-changes.html