# Deleting vs dropping user in mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, phpmyadmin

Im writing a bash script which is checking to see if database exists, if not then it will create the database and then the user.

```
db=mydb
user=user
echo "Creating database $db"
if [ ! -d "/var/lib/mysql/$db" ] ; then
    mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE $db /*\!CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci; */;"
    mysql -e "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS $user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$user';"
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $db.* TO '$user'@'localhost';"
    mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
else
    echo "Database already exists"
fi
```

What I am trying to do is:

If db doesnt exist then create it, there is an assumption that if the db doesnt exist then chances are neither will the user however, on the off chance there is already a user then it should grant the privileges to newly created db.
To test for all possibilities i'm using phpMyAdmin to save me time when checking but discovered a weird anomaly

- If user is created and I *drop* user from mysql console then script will
  recreate the user.
- If user is created but I *delete* user from phpMyAdmin, I get error below
  when script is re-run.

> ERROR 1133 (28000) at line 1: Can't find any matching row in the user table

I notice the difference in the two is the *drop* and *delete* command but why is it not recreating if deleted from phpMyAdmin, is there a record of the user somewhere when using *delete*?

Comment: *I notice the difference in the two is the drop and delete command* DELETE USER not exists. phpMyAdmin simply uses incorrect term for DROP USER statement. *I get error below when script is re-run.* What code line produces this error?

Comment: I think it's at

mysql -e "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS $user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$user';"

The strange thing i've noticed is if i drop the database and rerun the script then it will recreate the database but not the user unless i change value of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008674/12024635)

I think the issue was down to using delete and privileges remaining. I've run the drop command via cli and all seems to be ok now.

In phpMyadmin I can *delete* but dont have the option to *drop* users whereas i can see the drop option everywhere else.